# What advantages does the bitbucket branch structure provide?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, branch

I am using GitLab as a repository in my enterprise and I am trying to investigate some standards in branch management. I have seen [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branches-in-bitbucket-server-776639968.html), which is the recommendation about branch structure for Bitbucket.

I would like to know which advantages it provides in comparison to an easier structure like master branch and other branches coming from it.

I understand that the standard is a folder structure inside the *origin* server, where you can find: master, hotfix, feature, bugfix, and release folders, where each folder has the associated branches.

Is it correct?
Can you provide me with some more information to understand it better?

Comment: bugfix/foo is just the name of a branch. It's not a folder or anything like that. Using such a naming convention makes it easier to figure out what a branch is for, that's all. They're still branches like any other branch.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks! Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain you the difference between *folders* and *branches*.

A **folder** is nothing else but a folder, a directory. It can be in any branch. It contains project files, subdirectories, etc.

On the other hand, **branch** is used to allow multiple people to work on the same project without disturbing each other. Let's say that two people work on different areas of a project, but share some of the files. What they do is, both of them open their own branch, `branch_joe` and `branch_lidi` for example. Now instead of pushing to `master`, each pushes to his own branch. By doing this `master` (which is usually used for main project) gets intact. After they both finish their work on some subproblem of the whole project, they merge their branch with `master`. The changes are applied, merges happen and everything is great.

But why couldn't they push to `master` in first place? Well, since they are changing the same file, `foo.c` for example, problems would occur. Let's say Lidi changes `foo.c` first and pushes to `master`. Now Joe would like to push as well, but he cannot, because he is not on the latest commit on branch `master`. He would first need to pull, but now there is a newer version of `foo.c` on branch `master`. If he didn't change `foo.c`, his local version would successfully get overwritten since git would know that his local version is coming from previous commit. But since he changed `foo.c` on his machine, git gets confused. It is unsure whether to overwrite Joe's local file, not copy the file that Lidi committed or what to do. In such cases it merges a file into some temporary file with lines like this `>>>>><<<<` and Joe must manually edit the file to select what changes he wants. As you can see this is tiresome and time consuming.

But if they each worked on their own branch, Lidi would push new `foo.c` to `branch_lidi`. Now that Joe wants to push his `foo.c`, he would push it to `branch_joe` and since the branches don't overlap, the Lidi's commit won't disturb Joe's `foo.c` and he would push without problems to his branch. After they finish their job, they merge their branches to `master`. After merge, they can also delete their branches if they don't need them anymore.

Hope this was explanatory enough and I didn't lose you.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation, but it not was about how structure git branches. Despite this I find it good for beginners in Git.

Comment: Oh, excuse me but yes, I was more explaining why to use them. Structuring is yes, quite advanced git stuff (I mean structuring them properly). No problem tho!

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching more on Google and I found [this post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Very easy to understand how to works correctly with git, and with branching name conventions.

Hope help someone.